# How do you programmatically read the coordinate display format in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, coordinates

I'm looking for a property (or properties) that will give me the display units and the formatting.
[image]

I assume I need `IMap.DistanceUnits` but I can't find the formatting.  Is this exposed?

I am also interested in accessing the additional formatting in this window:
[image]

I'm hoping there's a `INumberFormat` property someplace that I can hook into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the mxdocument as IReportUnitFormat2 and try [NumericFormat](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/NumericFormat_Property/000v00000150000000/).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this yet, but the following property page can have a solution:
[IPropertyPage Interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/componenthelp/index.html#//001t000000sw000000)  along-with the
[MapFramePropertyPage CoClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/componenthelp/index.html#//000v000000v1000000)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the formatting, but the friendly names are accessible through the [`IUnitConverter.EsriUnitsAsString`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00420000023t000000) method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but are you searching for [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004200000030000000)? You can get these map units through [IMap.MapUnits Property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000mm0000000).